# Complex logarithm and argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have this question that I faced during my work in complex analysis. Is the following equation is correct where $x>0$

$\log \left(1+e^{-i \pi  x}\right)+\log \left(1+e^{i \pi  x}\right)=\log (2 \cos (\pi  x)+2)$

But If this is true, then why, when I evaluated the argument, I get $ i \pi $ not zero?
Can anyone explain?

Comment: How do you define $\log$?

Comment: The natural Complex logarithm

Comment: That's just a name. Again, how do you define it?

Comment: $\text{Log} z=\text{Log}|z| + i {Arg}  z,-\pi <\text{Arg} z\leq \pi$

Comment: a single-valued complex function, Ln z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You are working with the principal value of the logarithm, and so $\log(z)+\log(w)=\log(zw)$ holds when both $z$ and $w$ have positive real part. And that's the case here, since $1+e^{\pm i\pi x}$ has positive real part, since it's $1$ plus a complex number with absolute value $1$. Besides, $(1+e^{-\pi ix})(1+e^{\pi ix})=2+2\cos(\pi x)$.

Comment: Thank you, but If I tried to simplify each term individually then I get the argument of $i \pi $ ?

Comment: I could I know? You did not tell us *how* you have evaluated it. By the way, I used Mathematica to evaluate the difference, and I got that it is always equal to $0$.

Comment: okay thank you, maybe I have made some mistakes in evaluating the argument